# Console: Can't type special characters

Tags: tty, console

We have Linux-based computers (Ubuntu 14.04.4) prepared by another company to use their software. We have root password.
Those computers has no X Window System. Just consoles.

There is a problem with keyboard settings. I can't type several special characters: `>?:"{}_+@#$%^&*(`
I'm pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> and it should result with `>` letter but it still makes `.` (dot), etc.

What could cause that problem?
Where can I fix this?

Comment: Also asked on Unix and Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292378/